# Синхронизация Scroll в двух ExpandableListView

Tags: java, android, expandablelistview

У меня есть два `ExpandableListView`, которые находятся рядом с друг другом. Можно ли синхронизировать скролл в этих двух `ExpandableListView`? Например, когда юзер скролит первый `ExpandableListView`, что бы скрошился и второй?

Например, у меня первые три колонки - это первый ExpandableListView, последняя колонка - это второй ExpandableListView.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Как насчет вытянуть `onScrollListener` в обоих списках, и присваивать `dx` значение от одного списка к другому?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Нашла такое решение, код в  `Activity`:

```
ExpandableListViewSynchronisationTouchListener expandableListViewSynchronisationTouchListener = new ExpandableListViewSynchronisationTouchListener(this, firstExpandable, secondExpandable);
firstExpandable.setOnTouchListener(expandableListViewSynchronisationTouchListener); 
secondExpandable.setOnTouchListener(expandableListViewSynchronisationTouchListener); 
firstExpandable.setOnChildClickListener(expandableListViewSynchronisationTouchListener);
secondExpandable.setOnChildClickListener(expandableListViewSynchronisationTouchListener);
```

Класс ответственный за синхронизацию двух `ExpandableListView`:

```
public class ExpandableListViewSynchronisationTouchListener implements View.OnTouchListener, ExpandableListView.OnChildClickListener, ExpandableListView.OnGroupClickListener, ExpandableListView.OnGroupExpandListener {

    private static final String TAG = ExpandableListViewSynchronisationTouchListener.class.getSimpleName();

    private Context context;

    private View clickSource;
    private View touchSource;

    private View firstExpandable;
    private View secondExpandable;

    public ExpandableListViewSynchronisationTouchListener(Context context, View fistExpandable, View secondExpandable) {
        this.context = context;
        this.firstExpandable = fistExpandable;
        this.secondExpandable = secondExpandable;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onTouch(View view, MotionEvent motionEvent) {
        if (touchSource == null) {
            touchSource = view;
        }

        if (view == touchSource) {

            if (view != firstExpandable) {
                firstExpandable.dispatchTouchEvent(motionEvent);
            } else if (view != secondExpandable) {
                secondExpandable.dispatchTouchEvent(motionEvent);
            }

            if (motionEvent.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_UP) {
                clickSource = view;
                touchSource = null;
            }

        }

        return false;
    }


    @Override
    public boolean onGroupClick(ExpandableListView parent, View view, int groupPosition, long id) {

        if (parent == clickSource) {
            if (parent == firstExpandable) {
                Toast.makeText(context, "First expandable id: " + view.getId() + " group position: " + groupPosition, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            } else if (parent == secondExpandable) {
                Toast.makeText(context, "Second expandable id: " + view.getId() + " group position: " + groupPosition, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        }

        return false;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onChildClick(ExpandableListView parent, View view, int groupPosition, int childPosition, long id) {

        if (parent == clickSource) {
            if (parent == firstExpandable) {
                Toast.makeText(context, "First expandable id: " + view.getId() + " group position: " + groupPosition + " child position: " + childPosition, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            } else if (parent == secondExpandable) {
                Toast.makeText(context, "Second expandable id: " + view.getId() + " group position: " + groupPosition + " child position: " + childPosition, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        }

        return false;
    }

    @Override
    public void onGroupExpand(int groupPosition) {
        Log.d(TAG, "Group expand: " + groupPosition);
    }
}
```